# UpdateActivity throws 400 "Unknown activity type"

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I do have a Bot that is reachable via MS Teams. The bot sends an Adaptive Card with some Text and a submit-action. When the user clicks on this submit-action, I want to proceed the input and then update the prior sent Adaptive card via calling `context.updateActivity`. According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/update-and-delete-bot-messages?tabs=dotnet#update-cards), I can use `activity.Id = turnContext.Activity.ReplyToId;` to specify the message I want to update. But the call of `context.updateActivity` results in a 400 HTTP error, the message is "Unknown activity type".

Some investigation:

- This error occurs when I want to send another Adaptive Card and when I want to send plain text
- I verified, that the `id` of `sendActivity` is the same as `turnContext.Activity.ReplyToId`

Any idea?

Here is my code:

Adaptive Card

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Some text",
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
            "id": "Feedback",
            "value": "",
            "style": "compact",
            "placeholder": "Wie hilfreich war diese Antwort?",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "title": "⭐",
                    "value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "title": "⭐⭐",
                    "value": "2"
                },
                {
                    "title": "⭐⭐⭐",
                    "value": "3"
                },
                {
                    "title": "⭐⭐⭐⭐",
                    "value": "4"
                },
                {
                    "title": "⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐",
                    "value": "5"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "title": "Feedback absenden",
            "type": "Action.Submit"
        }
    ]
}
```

Sending the message:

```
private handleMessage = async (context: TurnContext, next: () => Promise<void>): Promise<void> => {
    const adaptiveCard = AdaptiveCardFactory.createAdaptiveCardFromTemplateAndData(AnswerWithFeedbackCard);
    const result = await context.sendActivity({ attachments: [adaptiveCard] });
    console.error("send msg with id " + result?.id);
}
```

code to update the message:

```
private handleMessage = async (context: TurnContext, next: () => Promise<void>): Promise<void> => {
    console.error("received msg with id  " + context.activity.replyToId);
    if (context.activity.value && !context.activity.text) {
        const updatedCard = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(this.botConfig.updatedCard);
        await context.updateActivity({ text: "updated :)", id: context.activity.replyToId});
        //or
        await context.updateActivity({ attachments: [updatedCard], id: context.activity.replyToId});
    }
}
```

Comment: We are working on it. We will get back you soon.

Comment: Thank you. Some additional information from `package.json`:
`"adaptivecards-templating": "^1.4.0",
        "applicationinsights": "^2.0.0",
        "azure-search-client": "^3.1.5",
        "botbuilder": "^4.11.0",
`

Comment: Any Updates on this?

Comment: Go through this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/39366fb546ac12724620dda001609dfddadf2e7c/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot/Bots/TeamsConversationBot.cs#L206) for update adaptive card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
const att = AdaptiveCardFactory.createAdaptiveCardFromTemplateAndData(AnswerWithAnsweredFeedbackCard, {
    answer: "Mir geht's super, danke der Nachfrage!",
    starsCount: context.activity.value.Feedback
});
const id = await context.updateActivity( { attachments: [ att ], id: context.activity.replyToId} );
```

This does not work, but this does:

```
const att = AdaptiveCardFactory.createAdaptiveCardFromTemplateAndData(AnswerWithAnsweredFeedbackCard, {
    answer: "Mir geht's super, danke der Nachfrage!",
    starsCount: context.activity.value.Feedback
});
const msg = MessageFactory.attachment( att )
msg.id = context.activity.replyToId;
const id = await context.updateActivity( msg )
```

So, you need to save the save the sent `msg` in a variable and set the `id` of this variable instead of using the "inplace"-implementation of `updateActivity`

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify the type like this:

```
await context.updateActivity({ attachments: [updatedCard], id: context.activity.replyToId, type: 'message'});
```